# Conceptual proofs for the computation of the structure sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ct.category-theory, reference-request

The following lemma in commutative algebra is important for the foundations of algebraic geometry:

> If $A$ is a commutative ring, $U \subseteq A$ is a finite subset generating the unit ideal, then for every $A$-module $M$ the sequence $M \to \prod_{u \in U} M_u \rightrightarrows \prod_{u,v \in U} M_{u \cdot v}$ is an equalizer.

Namely it implies $M \cong \Gamma(\mathrm{Spec}(A),\widetilde{M})$. The usual proofs I know of are fiddly computations with fractions (e.g. Theorem 1.3.7 in EGA I, or Theorem 2.33 in Görtz-Wedhorn). I have found two more conceptual proofs on my own (which actually work in a more general setting), which probably are not new at all. Therefore I would like to ask if they appear in the literature. Any comments are appreciated.

Both proofs use that $M_u$ is the colimit of the sequence $M \xrightarrow{u} M \xrightarrow{u} \dotsc$.

**A**. First observe that if $M_w=0$ for all $w \in U$, then $M=0$ (if $m \in M$, then $w^k m = 0$ for some $k$, hence $m=0$ since the $w^k$ generate the unit ideal). By exactness of localizations, it suffices to prove that each $M_w \to \prod_{u \in U} M_{uw} \rightrightarrows \prod_{u,v \in U} M_{uvw}$ is an equalizer. But in fact it is a [split equalizer](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+equalizer) via the maps $\mathrm{pr}_w : \prod_{u \in U} M_{uw} \to M_w$ and $(\mathrm{pr}_{u,w})_u : \prod_{u,v} M_{uvw} \to \prod_{u} M_{uw}$. $\square$

**B**. Consider the category $I$ with objects $U \sqcup U^2$ and morphisms $u \to (u,v) \leftarrow v$. Define a diagram $D : I \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathsf{Mod}(A)$ as follows: It is constant $M$ on objects, and on morphisms $D(u,k \to k+1)=(u : M \to M)$, $D(u \to (u,v),k) = (v^k : M \to M)$ (similarily with $v \to (u,v)$). Now we use that finite limits commute with filtered colimits (Mac Lane, IX.2). $\mathrm{lim}_{i \in I} \mathrm{colim}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} D(u,v)$ is the equalizer of the two maps $\prod_{u \in U} M_u \rightrightarrows \prod_{u,v \in U} M_{uv}$, whereas $\mathrm{colim}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \mathrm{lim}_{i \in I}  D(u,v)$ is the colimit of the modules $M[k] := \{a \in M^U : u^k a(v) = v^k a(u)\}$. The diagonal is an isomorphism $M \cong M[0]$ and the composite $M \to M[k]$ is given by $m \mapsto (u^k m)_u$, which is injective, but also surjective: If $a \in M[k]$, choose $\lambda \in A^U$ with $\sum_u \lambda(u) u^k=1$, then $a(v)=\sum_u \lambda(u) u^k a(v) = \sum_u \lambda(u) v^k a(u)$ shows that $\sum_u \lambda(u) a(u)$ is a preimage. Hence the colimit is just $M$. $\square$

Comment: Just a comment: your first proof is an unwinding of the simple proof "apply faithfully flat descent to the map A --> \prod_{u\in U} A_u".

Comment: @Dustin: You are right, this is just the usual proof that faithfully flat maps are descent. I wonder if this has been observed in this context.

Comment: @Martin: I heard this argument via descent over a decade ago, and had the impression that it was folklore for quite some time.

Comment: More simply, isn't this a special case of the fact that the sheafified Cech complex is exact ? (Hartshorne, III, 4, Lemma 4.2, p. 220)

Comment: @Damian: Yes, and this can be generalized to arbitrary Grothendieck topologies. This is actually the most general setting for the method of A.

Comment: A minor nitpick: the reference you have to MacLane you have only shows filtered colimits commute with finite limits on the category of sets. It is also true in Mod(A), where you use it (but not in, say, arbitrary Abelian categories, like Ab^op).

Comment: @Omar: Sure, but the forgetful functor from an algebraic category to $\mathsf{Set}$ preserves filtered colimits and all limits.