# Examples of descent in basic algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, descent

I'm studying descent theory and I recall that there were multiple instances before where I heard something like "we can prove this as follows, but this is just descent applied to [...]". Unfortunately, the only thing that I can remember is Dustin Clausen comment in [Conceptual proofs for the computation of the structure sheaf](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119935/conceptual-proofs-for-the-computation-of-the-structure-sheaf).

**Are there other results in "basic" algebraic geometry that are usually proved in other ways but can also be interpreted as descent?**

Comment: Well any "gluing" situation can be rephrased in the language of descent

Comment: Sure! Perhaps I'm still new to descent theory, but Clausen's comment was surprising to me. I'm pretty sure there are other less trivial uses of descent to basic algebraic geometry.

Comment: In his original Bourbaki seminars on the construction of the Hilbert scheme, Grothendieck points out that etale descent gives a "coordinate-free" proof of Hilbert's Theorem 90.

Comment: http://math.unice.fr/~carlos/slides/ihesAGjan09.pdf

Comment: @JasonStarr it's here? http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1960-1961__6__249_0.pdf

Could you point out where that is?

Comment: @Niels sorry, but I'm not sure how that helps. Would you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: What Dustin Clausen said is roughly the following: the presheaf $R\mapsto\operatorname{Mod}_R$ is a sheaf of categories on the fpqc-site of the affine schemes, therefore the Cartesian section is an fpqc-sheaf, which leads to the result. In this interpretation, "descent" is a synonym of being sheafy.

Comment: That link is not to the notes of the full Bourbaki seminar.  The citation in the full Bourbaki seminar notes is the bottom of p. 190-15 in the expose titled, "Technique de descente et theoremes d'existence et geometrie algebrique. I. Generalites. Descente par morphismes fidelement plats." (Sorry there are no accents -- they were causing problems with the HTML.)